# Kafka doesn't compress in snappy

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I'm curious and I want to check if the snappy compression works well with the java Kafka client.

In order to handle this, I set up a small program. This program generate 1024 messages readable data. Their size are of 1024 byte. I send these messages on tree new topics and after I check the size of these topic directly on the broker filesystem.

You can find this program through the following code :

```
package unit_test.testCompress;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;


/**
 * Can be use in order to execute some unit test on compression  
 */
public class TestCompress {

    public static void compress(String type, String version){
        Map<String,Object> configs = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        configs.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        configs.put("producer.type", "async");
        configs.put("compression.type", type);
        configs.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        configs.put("partitioner.class", "com.kafkaproducer.RecordPartitioner");
        configs.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092");


        KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(configs);

        Random r = new Random(15415485);
        int size = 1024; //1 Ko
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            buffer[i] = (byte) ('A' + (r.nextInt() % 26));
        }
        buffer[size-1] = 0;
        //System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
            Future<RecordMetadata> result = producer.send( new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("unit_test_compress_"+version+ "_" + type , buffer));
        }

        producer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String version = "v10";
        compress("snappy",version);
        compress("gzip",version);
        compress("none",version);

    }

}
```

I'm compiling this code with this following maven pom file :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>unit_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testCompress</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testCompress</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>  
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>      
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This program executes very well on my computer.

But when I check the results directly on my kafka broker it give the following output : 
[image]

I think that's mean there are no compression on snappy topic (but gzip compression works very well). I checked though vi the file

I'm aware about this issue on Kafka 8.2.1 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2189 
But I'm using Kafka 8.2.2 on producer and 8.2.1 on broker. I checked the dependency of Snappy as well. I'm using the 1.1.1.7

Have you an idea of how to enable snappy compression on Kafak ? Did I forget a parameter to enable snappy compression on kafka ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchange on the Kafka ML, the issue was that my Kafka Broker have to be upgraded to 8.2.2 version. It solve my problem.